# Как в php лучше сравнить два числовых массива c вложенными ассоциативными массивами?

Tags: php, массивы, arraylist, сравнение

Есть два числовых массива с одинаковой структурой, но разными значениями. Пример массивов:

```
$firstArray = [
  ['id' => 11, 'number' => 5, 'text' => 'Яблоко'],
  ['id' => 20, 'number' => 4, 'text' => 'Груша'],
  ['id' => 30, 'number' => 1, 'text' => 'Виноград']
];

$secondArray = [
  ['id' => 334, 'number' => 5, 'text' => 'Яблоко'],
  ['id' => 23254, 'number' => 4, 'text' => 'Банан'],
  ['id' => 52324, 'number' => 15, 'text' => 'Виноград']
];
```

Необходимо найти все идентификаторы (id) всех массивов в $firstArray у которых поля number и text идентичны с $secondArray.
В данном примере результат выполнения кода должен содкржать следующий ответ.

```
$response = ['11'];
```

Есть лучшее решение чем использовать вложенные циклы?
На практике каждый массив имеет больше 500 элементов, а также большое количество данных.
Есть возможность решить данную задачку функциями массивов php?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
$flippedMap = array_reduce($secondArray, function($acc, $item) {
    $acc[md5($item['number'] . $item['text'])] = 0;
    return $acc;
}, []);

$result = [];

foreach ($firstArray as $index => $item) {
    if (array_key_exists(md5($item['number'] . $item['text']), $flippedMap)) {
        $result[] = $item['id'];
    }
}
```

Вначале создаем массив хэшей из номеров_текста второго массива. Затем пробегаемся по первому. Если хэш, сформированный подобным же образом есть как ключ в первом - значит всё ок и складываем id в результат. Вместо md5 можно попробовать что-то другое попробовать, чтобы не было коллизий и что-то полегче в производительности, м.б. `json_encode` или что-то полегче.

---

Без хэшей (потому что они добавляют времени и отнимают производительность)

```
$secondArrayCount = count($secondArray);
$flippedMap = [];
$result = [];

for ($i = 0; $i < $secondArrayCount; $flippedMap[$secondArray[$i]['number'] . $secondArray[$i]['text']] = 0, ++$i);

foreach ($firstArray as $index => $item) {
    if (array_key_exists($item['number'] . $item['text'], $flippedMap)) {
        $result[] = $item['id'];
    }
}
```

---

но кажется по замерам самое быстрое двойной цикл))

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 6):

Попробуйте данную функцию

```
$resultArray = array_uintersect_assoc($firstArray, $secondArray, function($itemFromFirst, $itemFromSecond) {
   return ($itemFromFirst['number'] === $itemFromSecond['number'] && $itemFromFirst['text'] === $itemFromSecond['text'])
       ? 0 
       : 1;
});

$response = array_column($resultArray, 'id');
```

В функции `array_uintersect_assoc` (как возможно и в `array_uintersect`) при возврате из коллбэка значения `0`, в результирующий массив будет заноситься значение, которое является пересечением между первым и вторым массивом.

В данном случае если значения по полям `number` и `text` в ассоциативных массивах из первого и второго массива будут равны, то этот самый ассоциативный массив будет заноситься в `$resultArray`, в противном же случае при возврате как `1`, так можно и возвращать `-1`, значение заноситься не будет.

Для понимания какое возвращаемое значение за что отвечает в своих коллбэках сравнения, можно посмотреть как вариант оператор `spaceship` в документации (https://www.php.net/manual/ru/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.spaceship-op)

Comment: Пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. Дополнить ответ можно перейдя по ссылке [edit].

Answer (score 4):

1. Создайте Set, содержащий `number` и `text` второго массива (см. [`array_map`](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-map.php)).
2. Фильтруйте первый массив, используя например функцию [array_filter](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-filter.php).
3. Из полученного результата, создайте массив, в котором фигурируют текстовые значения `id`.